# Spark Shell -The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, sparkling-water

I am getting an error while running `spark-shell.cmd` with following paramters

"C:\SoftwareLibraries\spark\spark-2.0.1\bin\spark-shell.cmd" --jars "C:\SoftwareLibraries\H2o\sparklingWater\bin\assembly\build\libs\sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.0.5-all.jar"

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Can anyone help in this.?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

we faced the same problem when we pass multiple jars in double quotes with comma separated, spark-shell.cmd throwing an the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. even though spark-shell.cmd internally calls spark-shell2.cmd seems some issue. the moment switching to spark-shell2 every thing fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head, however I do not have a Windows enviroment available to test this:

Have you tried to escape the backslashes or tried to replace them with regular slashes?

e.g.:

"C:\SoftwareLibraries\spark\spark-2.0.1\bin\spark-shell.cmd" --jars "C:/SoftwareLibraries/H2o/sparklingWater/bin/assembly/build/libs/sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.0.5-all.jar"

Comment: I did but no results!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the prepared scripts for starting sparkling water as they take care of the jars and python files locations.

You can download official sparkling water distribution and run `/bin/sparkling-shell.cmd` script which starts the sparkling water shell.